# Invoke a function which is received as an interface variable in golang

Tags: go, reflection, interface, function-call

I have a code which is similar to the following

```
package main

import "fmt"

func PrintThis(arg string) {
    fmt.Printf("I'm printing %s", arg)
}

func PrintThisAndThat(arg1, arg2 string) {
    fmt.Printf("Now printing %s and %s", arg1, arg2)
}

func Invoke(fn interface{}, args ...string) {
    //fn(args...)
}

func main() {
    Invoke(PrintThis, "foo")
    Invoke(PrintThisAndThat, "foo", "bar")
}
```

This is not the actual production code, but this is a simplified version.

Question :- If I uncomment the line `//fn(args...)` I get a compile error `prog.go:14: cannot call non-function fn (type interface {})`

How do I execute the function which is received as the argument tho the Invoke() function?

What is the right way to achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You use the [`Call`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Call) or [`CallSlice`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.CallSlice) methods of the `reflect.Value` to call it as a function. As with all `reflect.Value` methods, this panics is `fn` is the wrong type.

```
func Invoke(fn interface{}, args ...string) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(fn)
    rargs := make([]reflect.Value, len(args))
    for i, a := range args {
        rargs[i] = reflect.ValueOf(a)
    }
    v.Call(rargs)
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/xGmNLDcLL_

Answer (score 5):

You can use a type switch like so http://play.golang.org/p/opotbIGdrA

```
package main

import "fmt"

func PrintThis(arg string) {
    fmt.Printf("I'm printing %s", arg)
}

func PrintThisAndThat(arg1, arg2 string) {
    fmt.Printf("Now printing %s and %s", arg1, arg2)
}

func Invoke(fn interface{}, args ...string) {
    switch m := fn.(type) {
    case func(string):
        m(args[0])
    case func(string, string):
        m(args[0], args[1])
    default:

    }
}

func main() {
    Invoke(PrintThis, "foo")
    Invoke(PrintThisAndThat, "foo", "bar")
}
```

But you kind of need to know what functions will be passed to make this work properly.

Btw you can turn `PrintThis` into a variadic function by using `...string` instead of multiple string arguments.

Comment: Is there a way to scale this approach to handle any type of functions? I have shown only two functions for simplicity.

something similar to `m := fn.(reflect.TypeOf(fn))`

Comment: @ManuViswam there might be, I'm on mobile so it's hard to playground, but it's kind of hard because it's strongly typed so the compiler wants to know what things are at compile time. Why are you using this approach anyways there has to be a better way to do this.

Comment: I'm writing a plugin for a test runner. The test core will send you a function object and its arguments, I have to receive it and execute the function. I'm trying to write a generic method for doing this.

Comment: @ManuViswam check out jims answer probably better suited for that, I thought you knew the functions being passed. I suggest reading http://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection as reflection can be dangerous

Answer (score -1):

You need to declare the parameter `fn` as a function, not as `interface{}`. How is `fn(args...)` supposed to work for `PrintThis`, with one argument, and also with `PrintThisAndThat`, with two arguments? You need to decide which type of function you want to receive and declare that as the parameter.