# Can a variable be used as a placeholder for a function call?

Tags: go

I am writing a program which has several structs and functions to handle these structs differently. I am having a generic function which calls the required function based on the inputs.  Is there a generic way to use the returned value from **getStruct()**?

```
package main

var X func(s []string) A
var Y func(s []string) B

type A struct {
    Name  string
    Place string
}

type B struct {
    Name  string
    Place string
    Value string
}

func newA(s []string) A {
    a := A{
        Name:  s[0],
        Place: s[1],
    }
    return a
}

func newB(s []string) B {
    a := B{
        Name:  s[0],
        Place: s[1],
        Value: s[2],
    }
    return a
}

func getStruct(t string) interface{} {

    switch {
    case t == "A":
        return X
    case t == "B":
        return Y
    default:
        return //someStruct
    }

}

func main() {

    buildNewStruct := getStruct("A") //Lets assume "A" here is got as an argument

    var strSlice = []string{"Bob", "US"}
    buildNewStruct(strSlice) //How to do this operation? 
                             //I am hoping to use buildNewStruct(strSlice) to dynamically call 
                             //either of newA(strSlice) or newB(strSlice) function

}
```

I have tried looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41660857/how-to-cast-interface-back-into-its-original-struct?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35753768/invoke-a-function-which-is-received-as-an-interface-variable-in-golang) the later is not exactly the same as my question.

Since I am new to go, I am not sure if something like this is possible.

Comment: Look at part 2 of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48492325/141555.  You'll do essentially the same thing as your `getStruct` does, but instead of using `t` to determine the struct, you will use information in the `interface{}` namely the underlying `type`.

Comment: IF your requirement is, given a slice s of len k, apply its values to the equivalent index positioned field of a given struct S, then i would use reflection.

Comment: @sberry right, and as per @burak, I would still have to validate the `type` based on my logic. I don't think there is any other way out of this. Appreciate for your help.

Comment: @mh-cbon the problem is, I have many different structs with the same number of fields

Comment: @sberry, sorry I understood what you meant by `type` now. My bad! I think I will now be able to do what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the `reflect` package to set the struct properties to the equivalent index positioned value from an `[]interface{}` slice.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    var a A
    err := decode(&a, []interface{}{"Name", "Place"})
    log.Println(err)
    log.Println(a)
}

func decode(dst interface{}, values []interface{}) error {
    rvptr := reflect.ValueOf(dst)
    if rvptr.Kind() != reflect.Ptr {
        return fmt.Errorf("value must be ptr")
    }
    rv := rvptr.Elem()
    if rv.NumField() < len(values) {
        return fmt.Errorf("too many values")
    }
    if rv.NumField() > len(values) {
        return fmt.Errorf("too few values")
    }
    rvalues := reflect.ValueOf(values)
    for i := range values {
        f := rv.FieldByIndex([]int{i})
        f.Set(rvalues.Index(i).Elem())
    }
    return nil
}

type A struct {
    Name  string
    Place string
}

type B struct {
    Name  string
    Place string
    Value string
}
```

prints

```
$ go run main.go 
2019/11/21 17:00:17 <nil>
2019/11/21 17:00:17 {Name Place}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the return type for the function.

```
func newA(in []string) interface{} {...}
func newB(in []string) interface{} {...}

func getStruct(name string) func([]string) interface{} {
  switch name {
     case "A": return newA
     case "B": return newB
  }
  return nil
}

func main() {
  buildNewStruct := getStruct("A") 
  var strSlice = []string{"Bob", "US"}
  str:=buildNewStruct(strSlice)
  if a, ok:=str.(A); ok {
     ...
  }
}
```

With this approach, even though you saved some code by calling a unified `buildNewStruct()`, you have to use type assertions to figure out what is returned from that function, so this may not make a lot of sense. It depends on your exact use case though.

Comment: I agree. I was hoping to find a more generic and efficient way to do this. I will settle with the suggested approach for now. Thanks for helping.